# Error creating an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm creating a login form. When the user logs in, it will lead to the home page.

I create an activity that has an `AsyncTask`. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
public class iniTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(GPSTracerActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Connect to server...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... url_req) {
        String url = url_req[0];
        try {
            Log.v("doing background", executeHttpGet(url));
            return executeHttpGet(url);
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            Log.v("Exception doing background","Exception:"+e.getMessage());
            return ""; 
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        try {
                           Dialog.dismiss();
                        // here when thing go    wrong
                startNewAction(result);     


        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.v("Exception process response","Exception:"+e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

Here's `startNewAction(result)`:

```
public void startNewAction(String result){
    if (result.substring(0, 6) == "300 OK"){
        Intent i = new Intent(GPSTracerActivity.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

The task starts correctly, but when I call `startNewAction(result)`,
it does not call a new activity. Why?

NOTE : when i enable if structure to test string == 300 OK it is not work ! why

I see this in `logcat`:

```
07-16 14:57:23.345: WARN/InputManagerService(37): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40777ee0
```

Comment: Have you checked that it returns the correct result? (i.e "300 OK") Also it seems a bit pointless having your onPostExecute method do nothing apart from call another method, why dont you put your logic there - especially as it is only 3 lines of code!

Comment: Thx I already did but it run nothing It didn't call out the intent activity it show log cat as above , THat's y i try it another way by call from method. 

The problem occur appear when i try to put if structure if i don't use if it will show another intent , any idea?

Comment: Not quite sure what your problem is, the error you've posted is from the framework classes for interaction between views and input methods (such as soft keyboards). Are you using keyboard input in the activity your trying to open?

Comment: thx kenny, my input is in edit text log in then send to server, as can be seen it will send the request ( correct ) then get response (correct ) it then has to do new activity ( INCORRECT ) , why?

Answer (score 0):

In your onPostExecute dismiss the dialog first.

```
Dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: oh sorry in my code i already dismiss the dialog just didn't put in above question

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution,there is an error because of the way i compare the string,

It should be,

```
      if (result.substring(0, 6).equals("300 OK") ){
                Intent i = new Intent(GPSTracerActivity.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(i);               
      }
```

Anyway, Thanks for ideas !!!